# Разделить число на тысячные wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть у меня дополнительное поле price, вывожу его через

```
<?php the_field('price'); ?>
```

Как сделать чтобы вышло тысячное разделение 1 000, а не 1000 ?

Answer (score 2):

так `number_format(the_field('price'),2,',',' ')` и будет что то типо `1 000,00`

Comment: number_format(the_field('price'),2,',',' ')   так может? все равно не работает

Comment: @reddyk что именно не работает number_format, или не тот формат ва выводит?

Comment: тот же формат который стоял т.е. 1000

Comment: @Naumov вы название функции в ответе поправьте-то.

Comment: @reddyk, оно не может не работать - https://eval.in/611989 Покажите побольше кода тогда

Comment: <?php number_format(the_field('price'),2,',',' '); ?> вот так делаю

Comment: <p><?php $the_field = the_field('price');

echo number_format($the_field,2,',',' ') ."\n"; ?> руб.</p>   вышло 55000000,00  руб.

Comment: @splash58 да опечатка поправил

Comment: @reddyk а вы уверены что именно там выводиться ваша цена?

Comment: да уверен, ковыряю loop, там же вывод, перед ценником ставил всякие рандомные буквы, раз выводит, значит там

Comment: @reddyk Может на фронте что то js-ом

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/\d{3}$/g", " $&", the_field('price'));
```

Comment: так тоже не получается. Стоит плагин ACF PRO, там числовые поля

Comment: не особо понял почему числовое поле не подойдёт, в регулярке как раз числа и ищутся. ошибка какая то возникает?

Comment: нет ошибок не выдает

Comment: тогда нужен `var_dump` этого `the_field('price')` , потому что со строкой "1000" (которая в вопросе, собственно, указана) регулярка работать будет

Comment: Можете подсказать как сделать это? совсем не понял

Comment: попробуй этот вариант `preg_replace("/([0-9]{3}$)/", " $1", the_field('price'));`
с числами тоже работает, у тебя где то ещё проблема, если не получается. а `var_dump()` это основы отладки, почитай по нему документацию, пригодится и не раз